Why does my div and its content get pushed out of existence when new info is loaded to the div below it?
My problem
I am making a restaurant search website with two main panels. The left panel is the mapPanel(where you select the location and choose the search parameters) and the right panel is the tablePanel(where the restaurant results load).
normal website layout
normal website layout
I wanted to make my website usable on smaller devices so with css I was able to put the mapPanel on the top and the tablePanel at the bottom.
small screen website layout
The only problem is that when I search for restaurants with this layout, the mapPanel gets pushed up and out of existence when the results load.
Small screen layout with results
Here is my html to maybe understand better the layout:


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
  align-items: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: rgb(67, 106, 223);
  width: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h4,
div,
input,
button,
th,
td {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Arial;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
  width: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  max-width: 638px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 65%;
  max-width: 1548px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 400px;
}

#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 2380px;
}

#mapPanel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 35%;
  max-width: 637px;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#map {
  flex: 1 2 auto;
  align-self: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 170px;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
}

#optionsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 149px;
}

#searchContainer {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
}

#currentLatitude,
#currentLongitude {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

#currentLatitude:focus,
#currentLongitude:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#search {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#locateMe {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#radiusContainer {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#radiusContainer h4 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#radiusContainer div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#radiusSlider {
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#minimumRatingContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#minimumRatingContainer h4 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#minimumRatingContainer div {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.rating {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.4s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.rating:focus,
.rating:active {
  outline: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.rating:active {
  transform: scale(0.99);
}

#orderByContainer {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#orderByContainer h4 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#orderByContainer div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.order {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.4s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.order:focus,
.order:active {
  outline: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.order:active {
  transform: scale(0.99);
}

#tablePanel {
  flex: 1 2 65%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.longth {
  display: inline;
}

.shortth {
  display: none;
}

th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 35%;
}

th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 15%;
}

th:nth-child(3),
td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 20%;
}

th:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 15%;
}

th:nth-child(5),
td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 15%;
}

td img {
  max-width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Use shorter versions of table headers if window is too small*/

@media (max-width: 1240px) {
  .longth {
    display: none;
  }
  .shortth {
    display: inline;
  }
}


/* For small devices */

@media (max-width: 1018px) {
  h2 {
    width: 0px;
    display: none;
  }
  #content {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #mapPanel {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    height: 570px;
    min-height: 570px;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    overflow: unset;
  }
  #map {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    max-width: none;
    min-height: 226px;
  }
  #tablePanel {
    flex: 4 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: unset;
  }
  table {
    overflow: unset;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  #options {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #bottomOptionsContainer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #radiusSlider {}
}
<header>
  <h1>Restaurant Finder</h1>
  <h2>Results</h2>
</header>

<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="mapPanel">
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="optionsContainer">
        <div id="searchContainer">
          <input type="text" id="currentLatitude" placeholder="Latitude"></input>
          <input type="text" id="currentLongitude" placeholder="Longitude"></input>
          <button id="search">Search</button>
        </div>

        <button id="locateMe">Locate me</button>

        <div id="radiusContainer">
          <h4>Radius:</h4>
          <div>
            <input type="range" orient="vertical" id="radiusSlider" min="200" max="900" value="500" step="100">
            <span id="radiusValue">500</span>&nbsp;meters
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="minimumRatingContainer">
          <h4>Minimum rating:</h4>
          <div>
            <button class="rating">2.5</button>
            <button class="rating">3.0</button>
            <button class="rating" style="background-color: yellow">3.5</button>
            <button class="rating">4.0</button>
            <button class="rating">4.5</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="orderByContainer">
          <h4>Order the results by:</h4>
          <div>
            <button class="order" style="background-color: yellow">Rating</button>
            <button class="order">Distance</button>
            <button class="order">Price level</button>
            <button class="order">Number of ratings</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tablePanel">
      <table id="results">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
            <th><span class="longth">Number of ratings</span><span class="shortth">Ratings</span></th>
            <th><span class="longth">Price level</span><span class="shortth">Price</span></th>
            <th>Directions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



What I tried:
At first I thought that the problem was due to making the mapPanel static and the tablePanel scrollable but when I removed the code that made them that way, the mapPanel still disappeared. I expected the mapPanel to not shrink at all and the tablePanel to load the content while respecting the minimum size of the mapPanel by loading the content below but it didn't happen.

Good job of creating a snippet, unfortunately it doesn't work or demonstrate the issue you're experiencing. There's a lot of CSS too, would it be possible for you to create a [mcve]? You might even figure it out yourself doing so.

The culprit is justify-content: center on #content. As #tablePanel gets taller, this rule attempts to keep both panels vertically centered even as their combined height exceeds their container. There is a very thorough explanation of it on this question about a similar issue, although in your case, just removing justify-content: center from the rule block for #content should achieve your desired result.
